PayPal JavaScript SDK TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function 'function(){if(!e)return e=!0,n.apply(this,arguments)}'
I'm trying to use the PayPal JavaScript SDK in my Angular project.
Below the complete code.
First of all I have added this line of code in the index.html file:
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>

paypal.component.html:


<div class="paypal-container">
    <h2>{{ 'PAYMENT.COINS_PACKAGE' | translate }}</h2>
    <div class="coin-options">
      <div *ngFor="let option of coinOptions" (click)="selectOption(option)" [class.selected]="selectedOption === option" class="coin-option">
        <h3>{{ option.coins }} Coins</h3>
        <p>{{ option.price | currency: 'EUR' }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div> <!-- PayPal button will render here -->
  </div>
  



paypal.component.ts:


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PaypalModel } from 'src/app/common/paypal-model';
import { PaypalService } from 'src/app/services/paypal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-paypal',
  templateUrl: './paypal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./paypal.component.scss']
})

export class PaypalComponent implements OnInit {

  // Variable to store the currently selected option (coins and price)
  selectedOption: any = null;

  
  // coinOptions: This is a list (an array) of objects, each representing an option the user can choose, 
  // with a certain number of coins and a corresponding price.
  coinOptions = [
    { coins: 100, price: 5.00 },
    { coins: 500, price: 20.00 },
    { coins: 1000, price: 35.00 }
  ];

  // Injecting the PaypalService into the component through the constructor
  constructor(
    private paypalService: PaypalService,
  ) {
    // This is a placeholder for future use if you want to check if a user is signed in
    // this.isSignedIn = false;
  }

  // Lifecycle hook that is called after the component is initialized
  ngOnInit() {
    // Load the PayPal SDK script dynamically when the component is initialized
    this.loadPayPalScript();
  }

  // Function to dynamically load the PayPal SDK script
  loadPayPalScript() {
    const script = document.createElement('script'); // Create a new script element
    script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR`; // Set the source to PayPal's SDK URL with the client ID and currency
    script.onload = () => {
      // Once the script is loaded, render the PayPal button
      this.renderPayPalButton();
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script); // Append the script to the document's body
  }

  // Function to render the PayPal button and configure its behavior
  renderPayPalButton() {
    (window as any).paypal.Buttons({
      // Function to create the PayPal order when the button is clicked
      createOrder: (data: any, actions: any) => {
        // Create an order with the selected option's price and currency
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
              value: this.selectedOption.price.toString(), // The price of the selected option
              currency_code: 'EUR' // Currency code set to EUR
            }
          }]
        });
      },

      // Function that runs after the payment is approved
      onApprove: (data: any, actions: any) => {

        // Capture the payment and get the transaction details
        return actions.order.capture().then((details: any) => {

          // Capture the current date and time
          const paymentDate = new Date().toISOString();
          
          // Create a PaypalModel object with the details of the transaction
          const paypalModel : PaypalModel = {
            payerID: data.payerID, // ID of the payer
            orderID: data.orderID, // ID of the order
            paymentID: data.paymentID, // ID of the payment
            coinsPurchased: this.selectedOption.coins, // Number of coins purchased
            amountPaid: this.selectedOption.price, // Amount paid
            currency: 'EUR', // Currency of the payment
            payerName: details.payer.name.given_name + ' ' + details.payer.name.surname, // Full name of the payer
            payerEmail: details.payer.email_address, // Email address of the payer
            status: details.status, // Status of the payment (e.g., "COMPLETED")
            paymentDate: paymentDate // Date and time of the payment
          };

          // Log the transaction details to the console for debugging
          // console.log: This logs the transaction details to the browser’s console for debugging.
          console.log('Transaction Details:', JSON.stringify(paypalModel, null, 2));

          // Send the transaction details to the backend server using the PaypalService
          this.paypalService.paypalPayment(paypalModel).subscribe(
            response => {
              // Log a success message if the payload is sent successfully
              console.log('Payment payload correctly sent to backend');
            },
            error => {
              // Log an error message if there was an issue sending the payload
              console.log('An error occurred when sending the payload to the backend!');
            }
          );
        });
      }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container'); // Render the PayPal button inside the container with the specified ID
  }

  // Function to set the selected payment option when the user selects one
  selectOption(option: any) {
    this.selectedOption = option; // Set the selectedOption to the option chosen by the user
  }
}



paypal.component.scss:


.paypal-container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #333;
}

.coin-options {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.coin-option {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.coin-option.selected {
  background-color: #0070ba;
  color: #fff;
}

.coin-option h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.coin-option p {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.paypal-button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #0070ba;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.paypal-button:disabled {
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.paypal-button:hover:not(:disabled) {
  background-color: #005b9a;
}



paypal-model.ts:


export class PaypalModel {
  payerID: string;
  orderID: string;
  paymentID: string;
  coinsPurchased: string;
  amountPaid: string;
  currency: string;
  payerName: string;
  payerEmail: string;
  status: string;
  paymentDate: string;
  }



And finally paypal.service.ts:


import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ResponseModel } from '../common/generic-model';
import { Observable, catchError, retry, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { PaypalModel } from "../common/paypal-model";
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }),
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class PaypalService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  language = "";

  paypalPayment(paypalModel: PaypalModel): Observable<ResponseModel> {
    return this.http
      .post<ResponseModel>(
        environment.baseUrl + "/payment/paypal",
        JSON.stringify(paypalModel),
        httpOptions
      )
      .pipe(retry(0), catchError(this.handleError));
  }


  // Error handling
  handleError(error: any) {
    let errorMessage = "";
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // Get client-side error
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      // Get server-side error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }

    return throwError(() => {
      return errorMessage;
    });
  }
}



Now, when I run this code with ng serve and I go to the page http://localhost:4200/app-ui/payment/paypal from the browser, when I inspect the page, even before starting the payment simulation, I get the following error when running in debug mode:


Exception: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function 'function(){if(!e)return e=!0,n.apply(this,arguments)}' at En (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:26592) at kn (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:29224) at Object.register (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:33033) at n (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:117879) at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:118145 at e.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:14426) at e.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:13483) at e.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:14646) at e.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:13483) at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:13127
message: "Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function 'function(){if(!e)return e=!0,n.apply(this,arguments)}'"
stack: "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function 'function(){if(!e)return e=!0,n.apply(this,arguments)}'\n    at En (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:26592)\n    at kn (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:29224)\n    at Object.register (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:33033)\n    at n (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:117879)\n    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:118145\n    at e.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:14426)\n    at e.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:13483)\n    at e.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:14646)\n    at e.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:13483)\n    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR:3:13127"
[[Prototype]]: Error
constructor: ƒ TypeError()
message: ""
name: "TypeError"
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: ƒ Error()
message: ""
name: "Error"
toString: ƒ toString()
[[Prototype]]: Object
this: undefined
e: "anonymous::once"



This is the function that triggers the error:


        function En(n, e) {
            try {
                delete n.name,
                n.name = e
            } catch (n) {}
            return n.__name__ = n.displayName = e,
            n
        }



Which is located in the www.paypal.com > sdk > js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR path.
Now, it's not a big problem because the payment flow works fine. But I would like to understand why this behavior.
Thank you!

Do not both add the script to index.html and use loadPayPalScript()  for dynamic load, that is redundant. One method or the other should be used.

So this means I can remove the script to index.html and keep the paypal.component.ts as it is?
